# Multiple backgrounds

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having problems with setting two backgrounds to one page. This is how it's supposed to look:

[image]

I've played around with CSS but nothing works, because all I see is this gray bg.png file:

```
#kontakt {
    background: url(../images/bg.png), url(../images/IMG_1340.jpg);
    background-position: ;  
    background-repeat: reapeat-x, no-repeat;
    }
```

Is it possible to divide the page into two like I intended to? Thank you very much.

If I use this CSS:

```
background: url(../images/bg.png), url(../images/IMG_1340.jpg);
background-position: left top, right top;  
background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
}
```

the result is this:

[image]

Comment: **repeat-x** not **reapeat-x**
Also,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467830/css3-multiple-backgrounds-one-repeating-in-ul?rq=1

Comment: Check out [This](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) webpage about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#kontakt {
background: url(../images/IMG_1340.jpg), url(../images/bg.png);
background-position: right top, left top;  
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that. You can see the result in my original post which I just edited. The photo takes more than a half of the page.

Comment: The image on top is from the first url. Basically, repeat-x is causing the bg.png to repeat only horizontally and it probably is of small size, due to which you can see the image below. I have edited the code a bit, but you may also need to play with [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) and [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)